# Counting directories' distance using a Perl script

Tags: algorithm, perl

I am new in perl and I would like to calculate directories distance.

Below you will find an example of directories' distance calculation.

Let's suppose I have this directories' list:

```
 abc/a.h                
 abc/clipboard/b.cc             
 abc/gfx/d.cc               
 abc/gfx/e.cc               
 abc/gfx/gl/f.cc                
 abc/gfx/gl/h.cc                
 abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc
```

The resultant table would be as follows:

```
       file1              |  file2                    |  Dir. distance
--------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------
     abc/a.h              |   abc/clipboard/b.cc      |  1
     abc/a.h              |   abc/gfx/d.cc            |  1
     abc/a.h              |   abc/gfx/e.cc            |  1
     abc/a.h              |   abc/gfx/gl/f.cc         |  2
     abc/a.h              |   abc/gfx/gl/h.cc         |  2
     abc/a.h              |   abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc   |  4
     abc/clipboard/b.cc   |   abc/gfx/d.cc            |  2
     abc/clipboard/b.cc   |   abc/gfx/e.cc            |  2
     abc/clipboard/b.cc   |   abc/gfx/gl/f.cc         |  3
     abc/clipboard/b.cc   |   abc/gfx/gl/h.cc         |  3
     abc/clipboard/b.cc   |   abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc   |  5
     abc/gfx/d.cc         |   abc/gfx/e.cc            |  0
     abc/gfx/d.cc         |   abc/gfx/gl/f.cc         |  1
     abc/gfx/d.cc         |   abc/gfx/gl/h.cc         |  1
     abc/gfx/d.cc         |   abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc   |  3
     abc/gfx/e.cc         |   abc/gfx/gl/f.cc         |  1
     abc/gfx/e.cc         |   abc/gfx/gl/h.cc         |  1
     abc/gfx/e.cc         |   abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc   |  3
     abc/gfx/gl/f.cc      |   abc/gfx/gl/h.cc         |  0
     abc/gfx/gl/f.cc      |   abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc   |  2
     abc/gfx/gl/h.cc      |   abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc   |  2
```

I believe this is feasible using Perl but I am unsure what code methods I should use.

Does some of you know an approach to make it possible?

Regards,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even if you're new to Perl, you should at least describe how you would do it (pseudo-algorithm)

Comment: count the number of '/' in each entry and distance is $n2 - $n1

Comment: Michael, I think your method $n2-$n1 would not work e.g.: abc/clipboard/b.cc   |   abc/gfx/e.cc            |  2                using your method the result would return 0.

Comment: Zaid I know how I can get the arrays for file1 and file2 and then comparing them. But still I do not know the best algorithm to return the table I mentioned.

Comment: @SamuelDonadelli This is problem is all about deriving proper algorithm. After that perl code is not that difficult even for beginners. You could have described your efforts.

Comment: @jkshah You said it all. The proper algorithm was the issue I had. Even being a beginner I was not able to solve it. Thank you a lot for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

The `sub distance` should help you get started. Call it `nC2` times using  [Math::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aCombinatorics) and you will get what you wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

distance('abc/clipboard/b.cc','abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc');#5

sub distance
{
    my ($path1,$path2)=@_;
    my @levels1=split(/\//,$path1);
    my @levels2=split(/\//,$path2);
    my $depth=0;
    for my $i (0..$#levels1)
    {
        if($levels1[$i] eq $levels2[$i])
        {
            $depth++;
        }
    }
    printf("$path1 $path2 %d\n",scalar(@levels1)+scalar(@levels2)-(2*$depth)-2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Suggested Algorithm**

Here I will be using file path in terms of tree data structure.

- Make set `A` consisting of nodes in the first path
- Make set `B` consisting of nodes in the second path
- Remove leaf nodes of both the paths from respective sets
- Take set difference of `A` and `B`. In short, `D = A diff B`
- Number of elements in `D` represents the distance between two paths in a tree

**Perl Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @dirs = (
                'abc/a.h',
                'abc/clipboard/b.cc',
                'abc/gfx/d.cc',
                'abc/gfx/e.cc',
                'abc/gfx/gl/f.cc',
                'abc/gfx/gl/h.cc',
                'abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc'
            );

for (my $i=0; $i<@dirs-1; $i++) {
    my $d1 = $dirs[$i];
    for (my $j=$i+1; $j<@dirs; $j++) {
        my $d2 = $dirs[$j];
        # Set A of nodes in path 1 after discarding leaf node
        my @d1 = split '/', $d1; pop @d1;
        # Set B of nodes in path 2 after discarding leaf node
        my @d2 = split '/', $d2; pop @d2;
        # Set difference D = A diff B
        my @diff = array_diff(@d1, @d2);
        # No of elements in set D
        my $diff = @diff;
        # Print result in desired format
        print "$d1\t| $d2\t| $diff\n";
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
abc/a.h | abc/clipboard/b.cc    | 1
abc/a.h | abc/gfx/d.cc  | 1
abc/a.h | abc/gfx/e.cc  | 1
abc/a.h | abc/gfx/gl/f.cc   | 2
abc/a.h | abc/gfx/gl/h.cc   | 2
abc/a.h | abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc | 4
abc/clipboard/b.cc  | abc/gfx/d.cc  | 2
abc/clipboard/b.cc  | abc/gfx/e.cc  | 2
abc/clipboard/b.cc  | abc/gfx/gl/f.cc   | 3
abc/clipboard/b.cc  | abc/gfx/gl/h.cc   | 3
abc/clipboard/b.cc  | abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc | 5
abc/gfx/d.cc    | abc/gfx/e.cc  | 0
abc/gfx/d.cc    | abc/gfx/gl/f.cc   | 1
abc/gfx/d.cc    | abc/gfx/gl/h.cc   | 1
abc/gfx/d.cc    | abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc | 3
abc/gfx/e.cc    | abc/gfx/gl/f.cc   | 1
abc/gfx/e.cc    | abc/gfx/gl/h.cc   | 1
abc/gfx/e.cc    | abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc | 3
abc/gfx/gl/f.cc | abc/gfx/gl/h.cc   | 0
abc/gfx/gl/f.cc | abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc | 2
abc/gfx/gl/h.cc | abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Including the relative paths between the two files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = <>;

for my $source (@files) {
    for my $destination (@files) {
        chomp ($source, $destination);

        next if $source eq $destination
            or $source gt $destination;

        my @sourceParts = split "/", $source;
        my @destinationParts = split "/", $destination;

        # ignore the actual filename
        my $sourceName = pop @sourceParts;
        my $destinationName = pop @destinationParts;

        # discard the matching parts of the paths
        while(@sourceParts and @destinationParts) {
            last if $sourceParts[0] ne $destinationParts[0];

            shift @sourceParts;
            shift @destinationParts;
        }

        # count the non-matching directories
        my $distance = @sourceParts + @destinationParts;

        # relative paths
        my $rel2source = "../" x @destinationParts . join "/", @sourceParts, $sourceName;
        my $rel2destination = "../" x @sourceParts . join "/", @destinationParts, $destinationName;

        printf("%30s | %30s | %30s | %30s | %3d\n",
            $source,
            $destination,
            $rel2destination,
            $rel2source,
            $distance,
            );
    }
}

exit;
```

Results:

```
               abc/a.h |             abc/clipboard/b.cc |                 clipboard/b.cc |                         ../a.h |   1
               abc/a.h |                   abc/gfx/d.cc |                       gfx/d.cc |                         ../a.h |   1
               abc/a.h |                   abc/gfx/e.cc |                       gfx/e.cc |                         ../a.h |   1
               abc/a.h |                abc/gfx/gl/f.cc |                    gfx/gl/f.cc |                      ../../a.h |   2
               abc/a.h |                abc/gfx/gl/h.cc |                    gfx/gl/h.cc |                      ../../a.h |   2
               abc/a.h |          abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |              gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |                ../../../../a.h |   4
    abc/clipboard/b.cc |                   abc/gfx/d.cc |                    ../gfx/d.cc |              ../clipboard/b.cc |   2
    abc/clipboard/b.cc |                   abc/gfx/e.cc |                    ../gfx/e.cc |              ../clipboard/b.cc |   2
    abc/clipboard/b.cc |                abc/gfx/gl/f.cc |                 ../gfx/gl/f.cc |           ../../clipboard/b.cc |   3
    abc/clipboard/b.cc |                abc/gfx/gl/h.cc |                 ../gfx/gl/h.cc |           ../../clipboard/b.cc |   3
    abc/clipboard/b.cc |          abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |           ../gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |     ../../../../clipboard/b.cc |   5
          abc/gfx/d.cc |                   abc/gfx/e.cc |                           e.cc |                           d.cc |   0
          abc/gfx/d.cc |                abc/gfx/gl/f.cc |                        gl/f.cc |                        ../d.cc |   1
          abc/gfx/d.cc |                abc/gfx/gl/h.cc |                        gl/h.cc |                        ../d.cc |   1
          abc/gfx/d.cc |          abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |                  gl/tr/aq/i.cc |                  ../../../d.cc |   3
          abc/gfx/e.cc |                abc/gfx/gl/f.cc |                        gl/f.cc |                        ../e.cc |   1
          abc/gfx/e.cc |                abc/gfx/gl/h.cc |                        gl/h.cc |                        ../e.cc |   1
          abc/gfx/e.cc |          abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |                  gl/tr/aq/i.cc |                  ../../../e.cc |   3
       abc/gfx/gl/f.cc |                abc/gfx/gl/h.cc |                           h.cc |                           f.cc |   0
       abc/gfx/gl/f.cc |          abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |                     tr/aq/i.cc |                     ../../f.cc |   2
       abc/gfx/gl/h.cc |          abc/gfx/gl/tr/aq/i.cc |                     tr/aq/i.cc |                     ../../h.cc |   2
```